# error FTK1013: could not find unicode byte order marker

Tags: visual-c++

What does this error mean:

```
Error   8   error FTK1013: could not find unicode byte order marker in the file 
tracking log file: c:\Users\ASUS\documents\visual studio 
2010\Projects\project\project\Debug\CL.write.1.tlog. 
The tracking data is invalid. c:\Users\ASUS\documents\visual studio 
2010\Projects\project\project\FileTracker project
```

Comment: Quacks like disk corruption, not good.  Better check it out and make sure it isn't time to replace it, ask at superuser.com

Answer (score 7):

.tlog files are created as the build goes, writing dependencies, command lines, etc, not anything directly in your control. You're not supposed to see that kind of error unless maybe your disk is full or you manage to launch multiple builds on the same project somehow.

Exit VS, delete the debug folder. Look around in task manager for stray processes or reboot.
Reopen the solution and try build, with some hope the problem just goes away for good.

Answer (score 2):

If someone faced mentioned error you should know that it's VS2010 issue only.
  It's already tested and checked. Be careful with following project names:

**mt, link, midle, cl, bscmake, rc**

In most cases you could just build your project again and buld process will be finished successfully, but if you want to avoid of this error at each RE-build(or first buid, or automatic build by some of control system) you have to rename your project. 
Also described and discussed in:
[MS Social thread "Error FTK1013: could not find unicode byte order marker in file tracking log file"](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f899e605-713f-4f5b-a654-898bde15ec7a/error-ftk1013-could-not-find-unicode-byte-order-marker-in-file-tracking-log-file?forum=vclanguage)

Comment: You can raise the issue with a with question on [Meta Stackoverflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) if you want the community to explain why your previous answer was removed.

Comment: Can't believe, I created a project named "MT" among the infinitely many possible strings in English language and it clashes with a reserved keyword! Thanks for straight forward ans.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the Debug folder in the Visual Studio project folder. Re-build.

Answer (score 0):

I am sharing one workaround for this issue.
Disable /MP for the project(s). Set value "NO" in the "Multi-processor Compilation" setting under Configuration Properties > C/C++->general in the project property window. It worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

Follow these 4 simple steps:

1) go in the Debug folder.
2) Search for the file.
3) Delete the file.
4) Build the project again.